# Android TextView's marquee does not work properly in RecyclerView

Tags: android, textview

I have a RecyclerView has some item in it. The item's layout contains a TextView. The content of the TextView is longer than TextView's width. So what I attempt to do is when I clicked one item then I want it to auto scroll the content. So I do this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="14dp"
    android:maxWidth="50dp"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"

    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/xxxxxx" />
```

And when user clicked one item. I do that item's textView:

```
textview.setSelected(true)
```

But the weird thing is that most item can do marquee but not the last one. On my android phone. The last textView has no marquee effect when I click it. In my friend's android phone. The last two item(textView) has no marquee effect.

I have debugged the code to see if there something go wrong but I found nothing. Could someone give me some hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Solve this problem today by just change the layout_height.

```
    layout_height = 14dp
```

to

```
    layout_height = wrap_content
```

It may be a bug or undefined condition that control flow flow into weird path.